# How can I update fonts-size dynamically using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to update font size dynamically so I have created this code but the problem is it is not working.

```
var font_size = 36;
$('#content').on('click', function(){

  $('#editor').css('display', 'block');

  var numbersValue = "<input type=\"number\" id=\"input-fz\" value="+font_size+">";


var currentValue = $(numbersValue).prop('value');
  var eleId = $(numbersValue).prop('id');
     $(eleId).change(function(event) {
      /* Act on the event */
      newValue = $(this).val();
      newvalueFonts = newValue;
      $('h1').css('font-size', newvalueFonts);
    });

$('#result').html(numbersValue)

})
```

[Here is my fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MyTests/0d9utwjc/5/)

Comment: `$(eleId)` should be `$('#'+eleId)`

Comment: As an aside, why would you use single-quotes for all of your string literals *except* for the one string where you want to embed double-quotes, thus necessitating escaping that you could've avoided?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably three changes required

1. Use `#` for id selector;
2. Delegate the event from body to the input element.
3. Add a unit like `px` as unit for font-size

```js
var font_size = 36;
$('#content').on('click', function() {

  $('#editor').css('display', 'block');

  var numbersValue = "<input type=\"number\" id=\"input-fz\" value=" + font_size + ">";

  var currentValue = $(numbersValue).prop('value');

  var eleId = $(numbersValue).prop('id');
   // Implementing point 1,2
  $('body').on('change', '#' + eleId, function(event) {

    /* Act on the event */
    newValue = $(this).val();
    newvalueFonts = newValue;
     // implementing point 3
    $('h1').css('font-size', newvalueFonts + 'px');
  });

  $('#result').html(numbersValue)

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 id="content">
  Some Content Here
</h1>

<div id="editor" style="display:none">
  <div id="result"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: there is one problem and that is sometimes it works when I remove the cursor from the input field and it incrementing or decrementing is not smooth. How can I solve it.

Comment: That because DOM updation take some time. Though the value is updated but still not refelected in DOM. In that case you can use setTimeout.

Answer (score 2):

Your ID selector is wrong, you are missing `#`

`$(eleId)` should be `$('#'+eleId)`

Also note, you should be passing `+'px'` as unit for `font-size`

By the time you are accessng the element using `ID` selector, Element is not present in `DOM`, use `html()` method before accessing element using `jQuery`

```js
var font_size = 36;
$('#content').on('click', function() {
  $('#editor').css('display', 'block');
  var numbersValue = "<input type=\"number\" id=\"input-fz\" value=" + font_size + ">";
  var currentValue = $(numbersValue).prop('value');
  var eleId = $(numbersValue).prop('id');
  $('#result').html(numbersValue);
  $('#' + eleId).change(function(event) {
    var newValue = $(this).val();
    $('h1').css('font-size', newValue + 'px');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 id="content">
  Some Contetn Here
</h1>

<div id="editor" style="display:none">
  <div id="result"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: there is one problem and that is sometimes it works when I remove the cursor from the number incrementer or decrementer in type number. How can I solve it

Answer (score 2):

& If Possible, you could switch out the templated element.

```
<h1 id="content">
  Some Content Here
</h1>

<div id="editor" style="display:none">
    <input type="number" id="input-fz">
</div>

<script>
var font_size = 36;
$('#content').on('click', function(){

    $('#editor').css('display', 'block');
    $('#input-fz').val(font_size);

    $('#input-fz').change(function(event) {
      /* Act on the event */
      newValue = $(this).val().toString()+'px';
      $('h1').css('font-size', newValue);
    });

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your selector is wrong. It should be `$('#' + eleId)` instead of `$(eleId)`. You also have to add `px` after font-size like `$('h1').css('font-size', newvalueFonts + 'px')`. Updated of your script.

```js
var font_size = 36;
$('#content').on('click', function(){

$('#editor').css('display', 'block');
var numbersValue = "<input type=\"number\" id=\"input-fz\" value="+font_size+">";

$('#result').html(numbersValue);

var currentValue = $(numbersValue).prop('value');
var eleId = $(numbersValue).prop('id');

 $('#' + eleId).change(function(event) { // Modified here
      /* Act on the event */
      newValue = $(this).val();

      newvalueFonts = newValue;
      $('h1').css('font-size', newvalueFonts + 'px'); // Modified here
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 id="content">
  Some Contetn Here
</h1>

<div id="editor" style="display:none">
    <div id="result"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: there is one problem and that is sometimes it works when I remove the cursor from the number incrementer or decrementer in type number. How can I solve it.

Answer (score 1):

replace your existing code with matching lines

```
 $('#'+eleId).change(function(event) {
  /* Act on the event */
  newValue = $(this).val();
  newvalueFonts = newValue;
 // alert(newvalueFonts);
  $('h1').css('font-size', newvalueFonts+'px');
```

as you not mentioned selector and you have to add px wih font size as font size is set in pixels